# Woocommerce HPOS products and customer missing in orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After manual migration from one DB to another, orders are missing details about products and customer. Every 'text-field' info is there, but its not linked to the user as a customer (under status) and also items are missing - only total amount is there.
[image]

Ive checked tables and everything seems to be OK. Ids are for relations are ok as well.

Comment: Clear transients , cache from Woo settings ? Rebuild the orders from the analytics settings ?